# Sqoop: -hbase-row-key as value

Tags: hadoop, db2, hbase, sqoop

When I launch the following Sqoop command for writing data from DB2 directly to HBase:

```
sqoop import --verbose --connect jdbc:db2://XXXX:PPP/DDDDD 
  --username username --password password 
  --table table 
  --hbase-table hbaseTable 
  --column-family cf 
  -hbase-row-key KEY1,KEY2  
  -m 1 --append
```

Sqoop import all data in my Hbase table and set as id: KEY1_KEY2

It is possible to import keys also as values in hbase table?

such as:

```
 TABLE_HBASE


id:KEY1_KEY2        cf:field1       value 

id:KEY1_KEY2        cf:field2       value

id:KEY1_KEY2        cf:field3       value

id:KEY1_KEY2        cf:KEY1         value

id:KEY1_KEY2        cf:KEY2         value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this problem

It needs to add `-D sqoop.hbase.add.row.key=true` to Sqoop command

for instance:

```
sqoop import -D sqoop.hbase.add.row.key=true --verbose --connect jdbc:db2://XXXX:PPP/DDDDD 
  --username username --password password 
  --table table 
  --hbase-table hbaseTable 
  --column-family cf 
  -hbase-row-key KEY1,KEY2  
  -m 1 --append
```